# How to call one async function inside another async function in flutter

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, flutter, flutter-layout

I have two future functions one for verifying OTP with API and another for setting a password using the API.

When the OTP verification is successful the set password API must be called. How can I do that?

My code is:

```
    () async {

var status = await registrationService.verifyOtp(registrationData.mobileNumber,otpController.text);
                                if(status == 'approved'){
                                  print('success');
                                      () async {
                                    var passwordStatus = await registrationService.setPassword(registrationData.name, registrationData.number, passController.text);
                                    if(passwordStatus == 'approved'){
                                      print('approved');
                                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, StudMainPage.id);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) => _showNewVersionAvailableDialog(context));
                                    }
                                  };
                                 }

    }
```

It shows error or the function is not being called. What should I do now?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `then` Callback

```
registrationService.verifyOtp(registrationData.mobileNumber,otpController.text).then((status) {

if(status == 'approved'){
   print('success');

registrationService.setPassword(registrationData.name, registrationData.number, passController.text).then((response) {

//....
})))
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Create a second async function for

```
Future<PasswordStatus> getPasswordStatus() async {
await registrationService.setPassword(registrationData.name, registrationData.number, passController.text);
}
```

and call that function as;

```
if(status == 'approved'){
   var passwordStatus = await getPasswordStatus();
}
```

then just use the passwordStatus value.